# Always taking default font when used family font like "Cordia New" in internet explore through HTML code

Tags: html, internet-explorer, fonts

Internet explore is displaying text in "Cordia New Regular" when I passed "Cordia New Bold". IE is taking default display font i.e. "Times Roman" when I deleted "Cordia New Regular" font from control panel even if "Cordia New Bold" font is available in OS.

Why IE dont understand "Cordia New Bold" even if it is present in system? How IE can decide they have to take "Cordia New Regular" font even if passed "Cordia New Bold" in html?

For information, same thing has been happened with "Courier New Bold". It means IE don't understand other family font like XXXX Bold, XXXX italic. It is always taking default regular font.

Code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

This text should be displayed in Bold but showing in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `font-family` property should be a name of a font *family*, not of a specific font (typeface). Here the font family probably has the name `Cordia New`, so that’s what you should use. And you should use `font-weight` to select a bold typeface if available (and `font-style` to select an italic typeface if that’s what you want).

The following code uses Cordia New as regular and bold when available, Arial or some other sans-serif font as fallback. Note that the principle is the same for Arial; we don’t declare `Arial Bold` but just `Arial` and select bolding with `font-weight`.

```html
<div style="font-family: Cordia New, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt">
Hello world!
<div style="font-weight: bold">
Hello bold world!
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `style="font-family: 'Cordia New'; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic"`

Be aware though that as Cordia New is not a websafe font, just because it shows up on your browser, it does not mean everyone else will see the font. If they don't also have it installed on their system, they will just see a default font.

Comment: Why italic? The typeface name does not sound italic.